# JDBC MSSQL SERVER Conversion Datetime Error When Inserting

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I getting the same over and over again.
I cannot use bind paramaters because I have some reasons
But I am just using a normal string query insert and update it giving date conversion error.

I have checked that my login account default language is English.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1488)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:775)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4874)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:633)
at syncproject.icstkFunctions.sendGet(icstkFunctions.java:2007)
at syncproject.icstkFunctions.mainRunner(icstkFunctions.java:52)
at syncproject.MainMenuFunctions.MainMenu(MainMenuFunctions.java:73)
at syncproject.SyncProject.main(SyncProject.java:15)
```

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT code
        FROM icstk
        WHERE code = '000000'
        )
    UPDATE icstk
    SET code = '000000'
        ,group1 = '0001'
        ,desc1 = 'DISPENSING'
        ,shrdesc = 'DISPENSING'
        ,unit = 'EACH'
        ,photo = ''
        ,remark = ''
        ,supitem = ''
        ,location = ''
        ,dfrdate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,dtodate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,ldate = '2017-04-02 00:00:00'
        ,lprice = '0.0000'
        ,openbal = '-433.00'
        ,maximum = '25.00'
        ,minimum = '4.00'
        ,cprice = '0.0000'
        ,uprice = '1.00'
        ,reorder = '9.00'
        ,addqty1 = '0.00'
        ,addqty2 = '0.00'
        ,addqty3 = '0.00'
        ,addqty4 = '0.00'
        ,addqty5 = '0.00'
        ,addqty6 = '0.00'
        ,addqty7 = '0.00'
        ,addqty8 = '0.00'
        ,addqty9 = '0.00'
        ,addqty10 = '0.00'
        ,addqty11 = '0.00'
        ,addqty12 = '0.00'
        ,dedqty1 = '35.00'
        ,dedqty2 = '22.00'
        ,dedqty3 = '24.00'
        ,dedqty4 = '22.00'
        ,dedqty5 = '49.00'
        ,dedqty6 = '22.00'
        ,dedqty7 = '42.00'
        ,dedqty8 = '32.00'
        ,dedqty9 = '28.00'
        ,dedqty10 = '16.00'
        ,dedqty11 = '24.01'
        ,dedqty12 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty1 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty2 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty3 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty4 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty5 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty6 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty7 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty8 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty9 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty10 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty11 = '0.00'
        ,adjqty12 = '0.00'
        ,addyqty = '0.00'
        ,dedyqty = '316.01'
        ,adjyqty = '0.00'
        ,minprice = '2.00'
        ,repack = 'N'
        ,totalval = '0.00'
        ,presc1 = ''
        ,presc2 = ''
        ,presc3 = ''
        ,qty = '0.00'
        ,poison = ''
        ,manufact = ''
        ,expdate = 'N'
        ,defuom = 'EACH'
        ,LastPurgeDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,Purge_pivot_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,Purge_Balance = '0'
        ,weighted_average_price = '0'
        ,Lastadd = '6'
        ,Returnable_Exchangable = ''
        ,Returnable_Exchangable_Status = 'E'
        ,nonactive_item = 'N'
        ,Disc = '0'
        ,Pfrdate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,Ptodate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,DiscRM = '0'
        ,Special_Register = 'N'
        ,Psychotopic = 'N'
        ,StatID = '0'
        ,Point = '0'
        ,Wholesales_DiscAmt = '0'
        ,Wholesales_DiscPerc = '0'
        ,ChkBalance_Status = 'Y'
        ,NewStkCode = 'N'
        ,EditStatus = 'Y'
        ,NotChkSellBelowAvCost = 'N'
        ,Dispensing_Item = 'N'
        ,Member_Disc = 'Y'
        ,WhRetail = '0'
        ,WhPharmacy = '0'
        ,WhBranch = '0'
        ,WhClinic = '0'
        ,Other1 = '0'
        ,Other2 = '0'
        ,CommRM = '0'
        ,CommPerc = '0'
        ,QtytoOrder = '0'
        ,EditTranStatus = 'N'
        ,TouchBtnPage = '1'
        ,TouchBtnSeqNo = '1'
        ,ScaleItem = 'N'
        ,FactorRate = '0'
        ,shrdesc2 = ''
        ,shrdesc3 = ''
        ,SpecialDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,PsychotropicsDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,EditTransDate = '2017-11-23 00:00:00'
        ,Cls_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,Cls_Balance = '0'
        ,Cls_AvCost = '0'
        ,StkModifyDate = '2017-10-30 00:00:00'
        ,EnterBillCost = 'N'
        ,Retrieve_Weight = 'N'
        ,NotAppearStkReorderRpt = 'Y'
        ,MultiUomDisc = '0'
        ,redempt_item = 'N'
        ,RedemptPoint = '0'
        ,Location2 = ''
        ,SynPrice_Disc = 'Y'
        ,TemplateCode = ''
        ,MasterRunNo = '1'
        ,GrpRunNo = '1'
        ,StkRunNo = '1'
        ,GSTCode = 'SR'
        ,Tax1 = 'Y'
        ,Tax2 = 'N'
        ,Tax3 = 'N'
        ,Tax4 = 'N'
        ,Tax5 = 'N'
        ,GSTPurchaseCode = 'TX'
        ,ExcluseUCost = '17.5591'
        ,average_Excludeprice = '17.6'
        ,Cls_ExcluseAvCost = '0'
        ,ExportShopify = 'N'
        ,Serv_Tax = '0'
        ,Serv_Status = 'N'
        ,DN_Status = 'N'
        ,Subsidy = ''
        ,NotIncludePointValue = 'N'
        ,illness1 = ''
        ,presc4 = ''
        ,presc5 = ''
        ,presc6 = ''
        ,presc7 = ''
        ,presc8 = ''
        ,presc9 = ''
        ,GenericName = ''
        ,WKRetail = '0'
        ,WKPharmacy = '0'
        ,WKBranch = '0'
        ,WKClinic = '0'
        ,WKOther1 = '0'
        ,WKOther2 = '0'
        ,SalesMargin = '0'
        ,StkType = ''
        ,TransportItem = ''
        ,PlasticBagStatus = ''
        ,Package_Code = ''
        ,MedicineStrength = ''
        ,MedicalChkStatus = ''
    WHERE code = '000000'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO icstk (
        code
        ,group1
        ,desc1
        ,shrdesc
        ,unit
        ,photo
        ,remark
        ,supitem
        ,location
        ,dfrdate
        ,dtodate
        ,ldate
        ,lprice
        ,openbal
        ,maximum
        ,minimum
        ,cprice
        ,uprice
        ,reorder
        ,addqty1
        ,addqty2
        ,addqty3
        ,addqty4
        ,addqty5
        ,addqty6
        ,addqty7
        ,addqty8
        ,addqty9
        ,addqty10
        ,addqty11
        ,addqty12
        ,dedqty1
        ,dedqty2
        ,dedqty3
        ,dedqty4
        ,dedqty5
        ,dedqty6
        ,dedqty7
        ,dedqty8
        ,dedqty9
        ,dedqty10
        ,dedqty11
        ,dedqty12
        ,adjqty1
        ,adjqty2
        ,adjqty3
        ,adjqty4
        ,adjqty5
        ,adjqty6
        ,adjqty7
        ,adjqty8
        ,adjqty9
        ,adjqty10
        ,adjqty11
        ,adjqty12
        ,addyqty
        ,dedyqty
        ,adjyqty
        ,minprice
        ,repack
        ,totalval
        ,presc1
        ,presc2
        ,presc3
        ,qty
        ,poison
        ,manufact
        ,expdate
        ,defuom
        ,LastPurgeDate
        ,Purge_pivot_date
        ,Purge_Balance
        ,weighted_average_price
        ,Lastadd
        ,Returnable_Exchangable
        ,Returnable_Exchangable_Status
        ,nonactive_item
        ,Disc
        ,Pfrdate
        ,Ptodate
        ,DiscRM
        ,Special_Register
        ,Psychotopic
        ,StatID
        ,Point
        ,Wholesales_DiscAmt
        ,Wholesales_DiscPerc
        ,ChkBalance_Status
        ,NewStkCode
        ,EditStatus
        ,NotChkSellBelowAvCost
        ,Dispensing_Item
        ,Member_Disc
        ,WhRetail
        ,WhPharmacy
        ,WhBranch
        ,WhClinic
        ,Other1
        ,Other2
        ,CommRM
        ,CommPerc
        ,QtytoOrder
        ,EditTranStatus
        ,TouchBtnPage
        ,TouchBtnSeqNo
        ,ScaleItem
        ,FactorRate
        ,shrdesc2
        ,shrdesc3
        ,SpecialDate
        ,PsychotropicsDate
        ,EditTransDate
        ,Cls_date
        ,Cls_Balance
        ,Cls_AvCost
        ,StkModifyDate
        ,EnterBillCost
        ,Retrieve_Weight
        ,NotAppearStkReorderRpt
        ,MultiUomDisc
        ,redempt_item
        ,RedemptPoint
        ,Location2
        ,SynPrice_Disc
        ,TemplateCode
        ,MasterRunNo
        ,GrpRunNo
        ,StkRunNo
        ,GSTCode
        ,Tax1
        ,Tax2
        ,Tax3
        ,Tax4
        ,Tax5
        ,GSTPurchaseCode
        ,ExcluseUCost
        ,average_Excludeprice
        ,Cls_ExcluseAvCost
        ,ExportShopify
        ,Serv_Tax
        ,Serv_Status
        ,DN_Status
        ,Subsidy
        ,NotIncludePointValue
        ,illness1
        ,presc4
        ,presc5
        ,presc6
        ,presc7
        ,presc8
        ,presc9
        ,GenericName
        ,WKRetail
        ,WKPharmacy
        ,WKBranch
        ,WKClinic
        ,WKOther1
        ,WKOther2
        ,SalesMargin
        ,StkType
        ,TransportItem
        ,PlasticBagStatus
        ,Package_Code
        ,MedicineStrength
        ,MedicalChkStatus
        )
    VALUES (
        '000000'
        ,'0001'
        ,'DISPENSING'
        ,'DISPENSING'
        ,'EACH'
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,'2017-04-02 00:00:00'
        ,'0.0000'
        ,'-433.00'
        ,'25.00'
        ,'4.00'
        ,'0.0000'
        ,'1.00'
        ,'9.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'35.00'
        ,'22.00'
        ,'24.00'
        ,'22.00'
        ,'49.00'
        ,'22.00'
        ,'42.00'
        ,'32.00'
        ,'28.00'
        ,'16.00'
        ,'24.01'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'316.01'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'2.00'
        ,'N'
        ,'0.00'
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,'0.00'
        ,''
        ,''
        ,'N'
        ,'EACH'
        ,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'6'
        ,''
        ,'E'
        ,'N'
        ,'0'
        ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,'0'
        ,'N'
        ,'N'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'Y'
        ,'N'
        ,'Y'
        ,'N'
        ,'N'
        ,'Y'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'N'
        ,'1'
        ,'1'
        ,'N'
        ,'0'
        ,''
        ,''
        ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'
        ,'2017-11-23 00:00:00'
        ,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'2017-10-30 00:00:00'
        ,'N'
        ,'N'
        ,'Y'
        ,'0'
        ,'N'
        ,'0'
        ,''
        ,'Y'
        ,''
        ,'1'
        ,'1'
        ,'1'
        ,'SR'
        ,'Y'
        ,'N'
        ,'N'
        ,'N'
        ,'N'
        ,'TX'
        ,'17.5591'
        ,'17.6'
        ,'0'
        ,'N'
        ,'0'
        ,'N'
        ,'N'
        ,''
        ,'N'
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        ,''
        )
```

Comment: That is one looooooooong SQL statement.  Please format it and indicate  which value can't be converted to `smalldatetime`.

Comment: Even formatting this SQL statement it's way too long, please keep it [short](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See [smalldatetime (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql) for the `smalldatetime` range of valid values.

Comment: You need to recreate your problem using a tiny throwaway table and brief code for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for smalldatetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql) indicates that the range of valid values for that type is

> Date range     1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06

You are apparently trying to store `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in such a column, which is "an out-of-range value".